# Continuously Get Data from a Non-terminating Program on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) C++

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-16.04

I have a situation where I rely on a third party stats polling application; the program is black boxed so I can only rely on whatever outputs that program gives.

Here's the idea:

- Start `get_stats` thread
- `get_stats` calls `stats -p` command (kind of like `popen("...")` )
- `get_stats` will continuously update some set of variables depending on the outputs from `stats -p`

Here's the catch: the provided stats program doesn't terminate, so `popen()` will not work for me. Ideally, I'd want get_stats thread to continuously update the internal vars based on the stats outputs. However, some occasional lag (~1 second or so) is totally acceptable.

Is there a way to do something like this? I assume it'll be platform specific, so as mentioned in the title, it'll be nice if you have a solution/idea for **Ubuntu 16.04**.

---

Edit: Here's a better [solution](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16539/get-real-time-factor-rtf-programmatically/) for my specific problem with gazebo:

The algorithm gz stats uses is the following:

- Get `sim_time` and `real_time` (up to 20 instances)
- Find avg `delta_sim` by doing `avg(sim_time[0 ~ 20] - sim_time[0])`
- Repeat above to find avg `delta_real`
- `sim_time / real_time = RTF` on the Gazebo GUI

Note: I used `avg(...)` to explain the algorithm, but the better alternative is to do `sum()`. `avg` isn't necessary because `sim_time` and `real_time` will have the same size.

Comment: I believe you may be looking for [dnotify, inotify, or fanotify](https://lwn.net/Articles/604686/) on Linux. Windows (NTFS) has similar features: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can you redirect the stats to a `unix-domain` or a `UDP` socket? You can bind your application to the `UDP` port and listen for the stats. You might want to add the channels of communication of this stats app and your own application.

Comment: @Azeem With `netcat`, or better one `socat`, it is always possible.

Comment: @Ho1: Yes. It sure is. I wanted to know the options the OP has to do this. Maybe, that `stats app` (most probably a `daemon`) has its own way of redirection which can come in quite handy without a third-party tool like `socat`.

Comment: @Azeem It's gz stats from gazebo: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/gz.1.html

Currently I use popen with gz stats -d 1 (run for 1 second, the minimum time. decimals like 0.5 will just round down) and just take the first line and poll every 3 sec, but I came here wondering if there are cleaner ways to do this

Comment: @C.Sano: From `stats` command, it looks like you'll be opting for the solution as proposed by @Ho1 in his answer. As this command outputs on `stdout` with specific intervals (`-d = duration` option), it can be redirected to a `socket` and your application can consume it. `netcat` or `socat` could be used for this.

Comment: @Azeem -d is how long the gz stats will poll for. default behavior is gz stats will run forever. My ugly solution was to set -d to 1 so it stops polling after 1 second and thus I can use popen to get the buffer.

Comment: @C.Sano: Got it. I was also thinking along the lines. BTW, how do you start this from your application? Can you not start it (as you're doing now) in a separate thread, get its output on a port, consume the output? Something like this?

Comment: yes, I might have to do that. Probably a `system("nc ...")` call

Comment: @Azeem .  see edit. I guess I just kind of blacked out and not realized that gazebo was open source. So the program is NOT a blackbox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `netcat` or `socat`, run the black box application in the background, and connect to the listening TCP or UDP port. All you need to write, will be a socket program in C/C++ that handles data which comes from the socket. You can handle errors, wrong outputs, disconnects, etc. through socket programming.

This can be a [good start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat#Making_any_process_a_server):

`nc -l -p 1234 -e /path/to/app`

Because you said that the application is Gazebo, you can use `libgazebo7-dev` library and control gazebo from C/C++ as described [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&ver=5.0).

Comment: unfortunately Gazebo does not have an API for what I want (real time factor). Note that its rtf from ~/diagnostics is wrong/not what I want (it actually is avg rtf), I want the rtf that gz stats outputs, which I couldn't find anywhere else.

Comment: accepted because this should work for the generic situation I described